# How many windows services can be in "Starting" state at once?

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I was writing some powershell code to start a number of internally developed windows services in parallel. The services don't depend on other services and I ran the Start-Service command in a loop spawning a PSJob per Start-Service call.

However after reviewing the events generated by Service Control Manager it seems like only one service is in Starting state at anyone time.

Fully acknowledge I could have messed up the powershell code but I thought I would check to see there is not a fundamental Windows (Server 2003) limit in play here (ie only one service starting at a time).

Daniel

    cls
    $Services = $('Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3')
    foreach($Service in $Services) {
      Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Param($ServiceName)
        Start-Service $ServiceName
      } -ArgumentList $Service
    }

```
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job<br/>
```

Comment: code added @shay levy

Comment: What's the status of the jobs?

Comment: Completed with out problem and the services do start, just 1 at a time

Comment: How do you know it's one at a time?

Comment: Inspecting the time stamps on the events generated in the system log by the scm

Comment: Jobs are created one at a time so they probably start processing one after the other and that could be the reason that the services and up starting one after the other, that doesn't say that the jobs are not running in parallel.

Comment: Do you think retrying using runspace multi threading will make a difference?

Comment: I don't know for sure, you'll have to test it. Out of curiosity, why spinning a job per service?

Comment: Because I thought it would start each service with out waiting

Comment: Also just tried a series of "start net start ServiceName" statements in a bat file, still starts each service 1 at a time

Answer (score 0):

Had an anonymous contact look in the Windows Source code for me and the answer is that only 1 service may be starting at anyone time. This is enforced by the SCM taking a global lock on the services database before starting a service.